# com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber$Exception: cvCreateCameraCapture() Error: Could not create camera capture

Tags: java

```
private FrameGrabber initGrabber(int ID) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    FrameGrabber grabber = null;
    System.out.println("Initializing grabber for " + videoInput.getDeviceName(ID) + " ...");
    
    try {
    grabber = FrameGrabber.createDefault(ID);
    grabber.setFormat("dshow");       // using DirectShow
    grabber.setImageWidth(WIDTH);     // default is too small: 320x240
    grabber.setImageHeight(HEIGHT);
    grabber.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Could not start grabber");
    System.out.println(e);
    System.exit(1);
    }
    return grabber;
}  // end of initGrabber()

private IplImage picGrab(FrameGrabber grabber, int ID) {
    IplImage im = null;
    try {
        im = grabber.grab();  // take a snap
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Problem grabbing image for camera " + ID);
    }
    return im;
}  // end of picGrab()

private void closeGrabber(FrameGrabber grabber, int ID) {
    try {
        grabber.stop();
        grabber.release();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Problem stopping grabbing for camera " + ID);
    }
}  // end of closeGrabber()
```

Why am I having such type of error?

Comment: *"I need urgent"* People reading that typically think along the lines of *"Too bad I'm too late! Oh well, there are a lot of people with better time management to help - I'll try to help them."* Or to put that another way, putting something like that is *less* likely to get help at all, let alone help on your 'urgent' schedule.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a separate block showing the full errors, including the Java stack trace.